# Array sort in 'asc' order php/Cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, cakephp

I want to sort this array on basis of 'eta'.Lowest eta must come to first.

**My array is :**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company] => Uber
            [type] => Saloon
            [eta] => 8
            [destination_required] => N
            [reject_booking_request] => N
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company] => greentomato
            [type] => Saloon
            [company_rating] => 80%
            [eta] => 10
            [destination_required] => N
            [reject_booking_request] => N
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [company] => CATALINA
            [type] => Exec
            [eta] => 12
            [destination_required] => Y
            [reject_booking_request] => N
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [company] => Uber
            [type] => Exec
            [eta] => 15
            [destination_required] => N
            [reject_booking_request] => N
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [company] => Hailo
            [type] => Taxi
            [eta] => 1
            [destination_required] => Y
            [reject_booking_request] => Y
        )

)
```

I want to sort this array on basis of 'eta'.Lowest eta must come to first.

**I tried to use this :**

```
 $result = Set::sort($array, '{n}', 'asc');
```

But it gives some error.

Comment: please provide the error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that in cakephp :

**My Ans is :**

```
Hash::sort($array, '{n}.eta', 'asc');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use usort:

```
usort($yourArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['eta'] - $b['eta'];
});
```

[Usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) allows the definition of a custom sortation callback function as the second parameter. Inside the body of this method you can define your comparison algorithm.

If the method returns a negative number it will move the $b variable down the array, returning a positive number will move $b up the array and return 0 keeps $b in the same place.

We have defined an inline callback method for simplicity sake.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. I added some additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array multisort function.

Follow the link for more information.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php